# Pull up FPGA & Pull down

Tags: electrical

Hi everyone I have a question that I don't quite understand.
Explain what pull resistors do in the FPGA, and why we use pull-up resistors for our button inputs.

Comment: What did your research tell you?

Comment: Welcome @NICK to EE.SE. You have to show some effort to get help. Show what you have found so far, what is your analysis ... etc

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please realise this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Ask a specific question, showing your work and findings so far in considerable detail with any schematic. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad idea to leave digital inputs "floating", so pull-up and pull-down resistors are used to pull the pin to a defined voltage while allowing other components to change the level (switch, etc.). The reason why leaving digital inputs floating is because they have a very high impedance and as a result are highly susceptible to external electric fields, which can result in the pin toggling or being left at an intermediate voltage for an extended time, resulting in increased power consumption and possibly damage to the device. Many devices will include internal pull-up and/or pull-down resistors to ease dealing with disconnected inputs. It is common for devices like FPGAs to use weak pull-ups on all pins until configuration completes. Depending on the FPGA, it may be possible to enable the pull-ups after configuration on a pin by pin basis, usually by specifying this in constraints files.